# Mosquitto 1.4.2 Websocket support

Tags: websocket, mqtt, iot, broker, mosquitto

I'm trying to utilize Mosquittos recent update to support websockets in the broker. I'm running Mosquitto v1.4.2 and I've added the following lines to the mosquitto configuration file (mosquitto.conf):

```
listener 10001 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets

listener 1883
protocol mqtt
```

When I try and start the broker with the new configuration I get the following :

```
$ mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
Error: Websockets support not available.
Error found at /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:16.
Error: Unable to open configuration file.
```

I was under the assumption that version 1.4 and above of Mosquitto has websocket support now (don't have to build from source to enable websocket support like you had to before v1.4) so I'm wondering what I'm missing. Any help on what direction to look to troubleshoot the problem is appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to mention I'm running CentOS6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the 1.4.x codebase includes Websocket support it has to be enabled at build time and relies on the libwebsocket library.

The builds currently available in the RedHat/Fedora yum repos do not have Webosockets enabled as there is no libwebsocket package available. I assume CentOS is using the same srpms.

See this bugzilla enrty for details: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1197678

Answer (score 1):

you can modify config.mk like this

in config.mk

```
# Build with websockets support on the broker.
WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=yes
```

then can you use a config parameter

```
listener 10001 127.0.0.1
protocol websockets
```

Comment: Can you explain these steps

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Paho Javascript client and the broker I setup on my local host, but I followed these steps and it worked for me https://github.com/bapowell/bapowell.github.io/wiki/Mosquitto-Build-Notes-(Windows---Visual-Studio), this is for Windows however, but maybe it can help you out

Comment: I tried these but it doesnt work, is there something im missing?

Comment: What to do when it is installed with yum?

Answer (score 0):

In the dir mosquitto-1.4.X
edit the file config.mk:

```
# Build with websockets support on the broker.
WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=yes
```

Then run in the dir mosquitto-1.4.X

```
make
sudo make install
```

Edit the configurations **/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf**

```
listener 10001 127.0.0.1
protcol websockets
```

And restart

```
mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```