# Mosquitto 1.4.1.1 Websockets Support Not Available

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, raspbian, mosquitto

I'm running raspbian on a raspberry pi and installed the mqtt broker v.1.4.1.1 and now I want to get the messages from the broker on the same machine (the raspberry pi) over mosquitto websockets.

I tried to set up the config file like this:

`mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`

I took a look at that question: [Mosquitto 1.4.2 Websocket support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383753/mosquitto-1-4-2-websocket-support)

But I can't find any directory called: `mosquitto-1.4.X`

Where can I find it and does this solve the issue I'm having?

Comment: How did you install mosquitto? with apt-get and did you add any other repositories?

Comment: You should probably also include the content of your config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X in `mosquitto-1.4.X` is for the version number and in the answer you point to they are talking about having built mosquitto from it's source.

When you download the source it unpacks into a directory with that naming structure.

It sounds like the version you have installed does not have Websockets support compiled in. The answer in the linked question explains how to enable Websocket support before rebuilding and installing.

Comment: Ty, I was confused by it because I thought that the answers are talking about an existing installation