# OpenWRT / LEDE: Websockets support not available for mosquitto

Tags: websocket, mqtt, iot, openwrt, mosquitto

I'm trying to run mosquitto with config:

```
listener 1884
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

I get an error:

> Error: Websockets support not available.

I'm running `mosquitto` version 1.4.14, I also have a `libwebsockets-full` (2.4.1-2) installed. I thought I could get the source and compile it with `WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=yes` set in `confik.mk` (solution found in one of answers in [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383753/mosquitto-1-4-2-websocket-support)) but on my router I don't have enaugh space to install gcc ;)

I'm running LEDE Reboot (SNAPSHOT, r5392-bc50a97).

Any ideas of how can I enable websockets for mosquitto on my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pre-built version doesn't have websockets enabled and you don't have room to install the build tools to rebuild it on the device then your only option is to follow the openwrt cross compile [instructions](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile) and build it on a different machine then copy the binaries/package over to the router.

Answer (score 1):

The latest prebuild version support websockets.

```
opkg install mosquitto-ssl mosquitto-client-ssl libmosquitto-ssl
```

choose the `-ssl` version of the package. Now your config will work.